# CSS a href styling

Tags: css

i have a href with `class="button"`

I am trying to style this like that:

```
.button a:link {text-decoration: none} 
.button a:visited {text-decoration: none} 
.button a:active {text-decoration: none} 
.button a:hover {text-decoration: none; background-color:yellow;color:blue}
```

why it is not working?
how to set stye for a href with that class (`class="button"`)

Comment: Put semicolon after each property..

Comment: @Misam. The last property in a css rule does not need semicolons.

Comment: Oh..thats Gr8..I never knew about that..Thanks.

Comment: @Caspar, while that's certainly true it *does* prevent subsequent issues/problems if it's remembered to use the semi-colon.

Comment: @Caspar you are right, but it looks so incredibly ugly and inconsistent.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`.button a` is a *descendant selector*.  It matches all `<a>` tags that are *descendants of* `.button`.

You need to write `a.button:link` to match tags that are both `<a>` and `.button`.

Answer (score 11):

`.button a{}` is a rule for

```
<something class="button">
   <a href="">foobar</a>
</something>
```

`a.button{}` is a rule for

```
<a href="" class="button">foobar</a>
```

Comment: how could i set for example a rule for a:link in that case ('.button a{}')?

Comment: oh ... then you simply write `.button a:link {}`

Comment: it is first thing i was try, but it is not working, it is working only that way a.button:link

Answer (score 2):

please share the html markup as well.

is `button` the class attribute of the anchor element or is the a tag a child of an element with class `button` ?

if its the former case, use

`a.button:link { }` etc

if its the later, your code is correct

Answer (score 1):

```
a.button:link {text-decoration: none} 
a.button:visited {text-decoration: none} 
a.button:active {text-decoration: none} 
a.button:hover {text-decoration: none; background-color:yellow;color:blue}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have said:

"An `a` element with the pseudo-class `:blah` that is a **descendent** of any element"

You want:

```
a.button:link { /* etc */
```