# Styling a link based on class of enclosing DIV

Tags: css

I though I knew the syntax for this but I am stymied.

I read [CSS a href styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856451/css-a-href-styling) and thought I got it right.

For to style these links:

```
<div id="anchorbox">
  <div class="anchors">
    <a href="#fre">FREE PEOPLE of COLOR</a><br />
    <a href="#sur">SURVEYORS’ MEASURE</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried

```
.anchors a:link, .anchors a:active, .anchors a:visted, .anchors a:hover {
  text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

and I have tried

```
DIV.anchors a:link, DIV.anchors a:active, DIV.anchors a:visted, DIV.anchors a:hover{
  text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

but neither worked.

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: You probably don't want to use the `!important` flag if you don't have to.

Comment: One quick pedantic point: Make sure you correct your spelling of `visited` so the links will not do as you're asking in your CSS. Quick best practices link on specificity: http://css-tricks.com/135-remember-selectors-with-love-and-hate/

Comment: @Andre - absolutely.  Added it in frustration trying to make it work.

Comment: @Scott - thanks, had missed that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.anchors a {
...
}
```

Should work. I think you have the problem because the order of active, visited and hover matters.

I got it working here also 
http://jsfiddle.net/BZETE/

Comment: Spot on. You could be more precise and use `#anchorbox .anchors a {}` as well.

Comment: Thanks!  Will accept as soon as SO lets me.  Why did specifying the selectors break it?

Comment: I think order matters :( now i only use a and a:hover. http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/link-specificity.html

Answer (score 1):

Seems ok, just remove the `:link` part from `a:link`.

Answer (score 1):

They need to go in a [specific order](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/link-specificity.html) and you misspelled `a:visited` wrong.

The reason why is to have consistency through all major browsers and specificity reasons as well - [reference](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/link-specificity.html)

Try this

```
.anchors a:link, .anchors a:visited, .anchors a:hover, .anchors a:active  {
  text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

or as how @Amir Raminfar suggested

```
.anchors a {property:value }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your styling should work; I tested exactly, and only, what you supplied and it styled correctly. This means that your problem is likely not in the cascade, but in specificity. Some other styling is being applied because its case is more specific than the one above.

Try: `div#anchorbox div.anchors a:(state){...}` and see if the added specificity resolves the issue; if it does, you can refactor back into abstraction.